# How to get line break in javascript inside variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array:

```
var social = [
 ["facebook",   "#link",    "#62b500", "images/facebook.png"],
 ["instagram",  "#link",    "#62b500", "images/instagram.png"],
 ["twitter",    "#link",    "#62b500", "images/twitter.png"]
 ];
```

I want to a add line breaks or space/margin between the icons at certain positions.

The result should look like this:

```
Facebook
Instagram
----linebreak/free space---
twitter
----linebreak/free space---
something else
something else
something else
```

My transformation-code so far looks like this:

```
$("#socialside").append('<ul class="mainul"></ul>');

    /// generating bars
    for(var i=0;i<social.length;i++){
    $(".mainul").append("<li>" + '<ul class="scli" style="background-color:' + social[i][2] + '">' +
                        '<li>' + social[i][0] + '<img src="' + social[i][3] + '"/></li></ul></li>');
                    }
```

What possibilities do I have to add a line-break/space?
How can I achieve this in my JavaScript?

Comment: How are you outputting the `social` variable to generate the example you posted?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript; the solution involves the way that the information in that array is being added to a page, but you didn't post any of that.

Comment: Ohh, im sorry. Added to original post.

Comment: And you want to determine the positions of the line-breaks yourself?

Comment: Yes, sir. Not the same position everytime. After 3 icons, then after 2 icons, then after 5icons. So different each time.

Comment: And do you have at least some rule for how the spacing should be?

Comment: Nop. Btw, by just adding <br /> at the end i can get the linebreaks for each element, but this is not what i want. I want to make it so i can choose, after which element i need that brake :s

Comment: If you don't pass us a rule, we can't suggest anything useful.

Comment: And is it always the same space, or should that vary somehow? And why exactly do you have an UL with the class of scli for each icon?

Answer (score 0):

I made it like this one. Will it be good enough?
I will have to create a new loop each time i want a different spacing, but atleast it works for me.

Created a loop that will end on 3 element. Then created the same loop starting from 3 to 4 element and added `</br>` at the beginning.

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    $(".mainul").append("<li>" + '<ul class="scli" style="background-color:' + social[i][2] + '">' +
                        '<li>' + social[i][0] + '<img src="' + social[i][3] + '"/></li></ul></li>');

                    }


    for(var i=3;i<4;i++){
    $(".mainul").append("</br><li>" + '<ul class="scli" style="background-color:' + social[i][2] + '">' +
                        '<li>' + social[i][0] + '<img src="' + social[i][3] + '"/></li></ul></li>');
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A `<br>` or an empty `<li></li>` would do the job.